# Save PDF file in PhoneGap Application that is Accessable by other Apps? (iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I have a PhoneGap App (iOS).

I have PDF data that I would like to save to the local filesystem.  I am using the following code:

```
                var gotFS = function( fileSystem ) {
                    fileSystem.root.getFile( "test.pdf", { create: true, exclusive: false }, gotFileEntry, fail );
                };

                var gotFileEntry = function( fileEntry ) {
                    fileEntry.createWriter( gotFileWriter, fail );
                };

                var gotFileWriter = function( writer ) {
                    writer.write( pdf );
                };

                var fail = function( error ) {
                    console.log( error.code );
                };

                window.requestFileSystem( LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail );
```

This works, however the PDF file is only accessible by my own app.

What I would really like, is to save the PDF document to the filesystem so that it is accessible by other iOS apps that read PDFs.  Is this possible?  If so, how do I do this?

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but just on iOS 8 and greater, but the truth is, I can't find any information about how to do it, I just found information about how to get files from other apps:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentPickerProgrammingGuide/AccessingDocuments/AccessingDocuments.html

There is another option, the "Open With", that allows your app to launch an "Open With" dialog that shows the apps that can open the file. You have some plugins for that 
https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2